# if statement in preg_replace function

Tags: php, if-statement, preg-replace

I am having troubles spliting a string as followed :
what is text to remain a text what is link to be transformed in anchor and what is link from youtube to convert it to iframe tag.

My script looks like this :

```
$string='This is a link www.dinamomania.net this is a http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9LB6qGvdpQ';
echo makelink($string);

 function makeLink($string){

 /*** make sure there is an http:// on all URLs ***/
 $string = preg_replace("/([^\w\/])(www\.[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i", "$1http://$2",$string);
 /*** make all URLs links ***/

$string = preg_replace('/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i','<a target="_blank" href="$1">$1</A>',$string);

$string = preg_replace('/((http|ftp)\:\/\/)?([w]{3}\.)?(youtube\.)([a-z]{2,4})(\/watch\?v=)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(\&feature=)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/', '<iframe style= "margin:15px 0 15px 0;display:block;" width="500" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$7" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',$string);

 /*** make all emails hot links ***/

 $string = preg_replace("/([\w-?&;#~=\.\/]+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{1,3})(\]?))/i","<A HREF=\"mailto:$1\">$1</A>",$string);

 return $string;

}

}
```

Everything it's working how it's supposed to just that, i get an anchor like this "> before the iframe, thats because first it's doing the link into anchors and then the iframe for youtube format. So it's an inframe into an anchor.

I was looking for an if statement to do something like this :

```
if( is link from youtube ) {
    // do the iframe part 
} else {
    // do the anchor part
}
```

Any help/advice will be highly appreciated. Thanks !

I have came with something like this :

```
    if (preg_match("/((http|ftp)\:\/\/)?([w]{3}\.)?(youtube\.)([a-z]{2,4})(\/watch\?v=)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(\&feature=)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/", $string))
    {
$string = preg_replace('/((http|ftp)\:\/\/)?([w]{3}\.)?(youtube\.)([a-z]{2,4})(\/watch\?v=)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(\&feature=)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/', '<iframe style= "margin:15px 0 15px 0;display:block;" width="500" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$7" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',$string);
    } else {
$string = preg_replace('/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i','<a target="_blank" href="$1">$1</A>',$string);
    }
```

But yet again it's doing my iframe part and nothing happends with anchors.

Comment: Check the [**`preg_replace_callback()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **this pattern** for URL

```
preg_replace('/([^\'"])((ht|f)tps?:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i',
    '$1<A target="_blank" href="$2">$2</A>',$string);
```

And **put the `IFRAME` placing statement before `A` tag placing statement**.

```
    /*** make all the IFrame links ***/
$string = preg_replace(
'/((http|ftp)\:\/\/)?([w]{3}\.)?(youtube\.)([a-z]{2,4})(\/watch\?v=)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(\&feature=)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/', 
'<iframe style= "margin:15px 0 15px 0;display:block;" width="500" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$7" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
$string);

/*** make all URLs links ***/
$string = preg_replace('/([^\'"])((ht|f)tps?:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i',
        '$1<A target="_blank" href="$2">$2</A>',$string);
```

See [how it works](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Dt5UQ8).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex approach:

```
if (preg_match("/http://(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?v=|\.be/)(\w*)(&(amp;)?[\w\?=]*)?/i", $link))
{
    // It's a Youtube link!
}
```

But can also use this approach:

```
$parsedlink = parse_url($link);

if ($parsedlink['host'] == 'www.youtube.com')
{
    // It's a Youtube link!
}
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your quick response , I have tried this before, but the idea is that I have more than 1 link and I cant parse all urls or I dont know how cause I am not so experienced in php.

Comment: So first of all you have to create a regex to get ALL the links presents in your string... then you modify them one by one and you rebuild the string.